# Find the expectation and variance of the random variable $X$ in the following cases:

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Find the expectation and variance of the random variable $X$ in the following cases:

$a)$ If $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$ for $-\infty <x<\infty$

$b)$ If

\begin{cases} 
      0 & x<0 \\
      1-\cos x & 0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2} \\
      1 & x>\frac{\pi}{2} 
   \end{cases}

**Attempt:**

$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, x\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}\right)\, dx = \int _{-\infty \:}^0x\frac{1}{2}e^{-\left(-x\right)}\, dx+\int _0^{\infty \:}x\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\, dx = -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=0$$

$$E(X^2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, x^2\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}\right)\, dx =\int _{-\infty \:}^0x^2\frac{1}{2}e^{-\left(-x\right)}dx+\int _0^{\infty \:}x^2\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}dx=1+1=2$$

$$Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2=2$$

Is this correct?

For $b)$, we must differentiate and repeat what we did above, right?

Comment: For non-negative valued random variables, mean and variance can be found directly from the distribution function.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what is given to you in b) is a  distribution function. (It is not a density function since the integral is $\infty$).

The density function is $f(x) =\sin x$ for $0<x<\frac {\pi} 2$.

Hence the expectation is  $\int_0^{\pi/2}x \sin x dx$ and the variance is $\int_0^{\pi/2}x^{2} \sin x dx-(\int_0^{\pi/2}x \sin x dx)^{2}$. To evaluate these integrals you have to integrate by parts. For example $\int_0^{\pi/2}x \sin x dx=-x\cos x |_0^{\pi/2}+\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos x dx=1$.

For $\int_0^{\pi/2}x^{2} \sin x dx$ you have to integrate by parts twice. I will let you do this calculation.